# How to load model on the fly angularjs Select combo box

Tags: angularjs, combobox, angular-ui-select, angularjs-select2, angularjs-select

At the moment I have a [combo box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box). In my appservice, I query my database and grab top ten.

```
<select id="StationSelectionCombobox"
        name="Country"
        ng-options="s.amenityUID as s.amenityName for s in  vm.nearbyStations"
        ng-model="vm.stations[$index].amenityUID"
        ng-change="vm.updateStation($index)"
        class="form-control bs-select drop-down"
        ui-jq="selectpicker">
    <option value="">@L("NotSelected")</option>
</select>
```

I am looking to update the model on the fly as characters are entered. May I ask how abouts should I do that, or if this is even capable with this control.

Comment: So you have an input somewhere that when you type it would update the select options? Hard to determine from your limited code here, but if I am guessing correctly you would use ng-change on the input. Having a bigger picture of your controller and additional html would be helpful though.

Comment: Combo boxes are not native to HTML or AngularJS. They require a third-party library or a custom directive. Is `ui-jq` a custom directive that is integrated with the AngularJS framework? Consider the [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) directive which plays nicely with the ngModelController, `ng-model`, and validation directives such as `ng-required`.

Comment: you can use 'ng-init' and controls logic from controller.

Comment: @AbuSufian The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`.

Answer (score 0):

[Combo boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box) are not native to HTML4 or AngularJS. They require a third-party library or a custom directive.

Consider using these libraries:

- [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) directive which plays nicely with the ngModelController, `ng-model`, and validation directives such as `ng-required`.
- [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) AngularJS-native version of [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/).

---

### Using `<datalist>` element as a combo box

HTML5 has the `<datalist>` element which can act as a combobox:

```
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice"
       name="ice-cream-choice" ng-model="flavorChoice" />    
<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">              
    <option ng-repeat="choice in choicesArr | filter : flavorChoice | limitTo : 5"
            ng-value="choice">
    </option>
</datalist>
```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<datalist>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)